# Laravel: Cache external images

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

There's a way to cache external images that are called by a webservice?

Eg:

```
$product_image = 'https://webservice.com/DOC/GetDoc.aspx?accesskey=XXX&filename=168724.jpg
<img src="{{ $product_image }}" width="90" alt="" />
```

Comment: Yes. Use a CDN.

Comment: First check if the webservice is already adding the cache control headers in the image because in that case you wouldn't need to do anything. If they don't then you could create a proxy in your own code to stream the file and either cache it using your server cache or adding the cache control headers so the clients can cache it (or both)

Comment: Yes, you could retrieve the file and write it to your filesystem